# How can you find and replace text in wordpress files on localhost xampp folders?

Tags: content, customization, netbeans

I am trying to do some find and replace in files tasks to my Local Wordpress installation with Xampp.

But some text can't be found, for example content text.

I have a multisite and I want total control on my code and files.

What is the best solution to find and replace in files for that situation?

I have tried Brackets and Netbeans, but both can't find text in content.

As a side note, I could successfully find and replace content text in Drupal, they are both PHP CMS so I thought it might be the same?

I need this to find and replace multiple instances of content on my multi sites and themes, mass changes to style sheets links for example.

Comment: What content?  Text in templates or in posts?  CSS files shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Content that is added to pages, home page text. I know that php is dynamically generated, but I cant' even find the text string in Phpmadmin...like the text doesn't even exist...

Comment: It's in there somewhere. If you're looking for links to stylesheets you probably won't find them.  They are generated based on subsite URL and theme/plugin location.

Comment: Lets do one by one. To replace content string with some other intended string, please use ["Search and Replace"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/screenshots/) plugin. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That would work no problem, but I wonder why it can't be done with searching files on folders on local machine like:C:\xampp\htdocs\wp_testing , with Brackets and Netbeans, Drupal site on local host can be searched, is this a Worpress thing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can as a general rule just use a simplistic text search to find content even in Drupal.

Any non-trivial data organization will probably use serialization, json encoding or totally separating the location of different parts of a data at different places of the DB or code and combining them when a page is generated.

A leading element in "what you see is not what you have written" are shortcodes, which generate html which seems to be part of the content, but it is not as it is generated from meta data or external resources.

The more complex the site is the bigger the chance is that you will run into content that is composed that way.

Comment: Well, thanks for the aswer, but I CAN find and replace content on Drupal site with netbeans and brackets, so I don't know what is going on with wordpress, as I said before, I can't even find the content in PHpmyadmin...help!

Comment: Just because you can in one specific case doesn't mean that you can in general @BrunoVincent